# I cannot access Tomcat manager via chrome browser, although it works on Edge

Tags: tomcat8.5

I edited the tomcat-users.xml file. It works on Microsoft Edge, but not Google chrome.

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script,manager-jmx"/>
```

Comment: What does `cannot access` mean? Any kind of error, incorrect behaviour or what? Can you be more specific with your question please? Welcome to SO.

Comment: Sorry for being late.
cannot access means the browser opens Tomcat home page, but not the manager page and I get Error 401.